# Android App links not working with actual android device browser

Tags: java, android, android-app-links, digital-assets-links

I have updated my current play store app with the Instant app feature enabled.

Also, in the same app, I have added the android app links using the below document.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing

I have followed all the steps correctly mentioned in the docs.

It has been implemented all perfectly as I have tested the URL through App Link Assistant from the studio.

The URL also worked perfectly with the emulator and open an app as expected.

I have used the below command to run an app in the emulator.

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW \-c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE \-d "https://[domain name]/preview"
```

/preview is my pathPattern

So the question is why the URL is not working when opening it from the Android browser directly?
As my application is uploaded on play store and assetlink.json file is also uploaded on my running domain.

Could you guys please help me out to find out the missing element or a direction?

Comment: Have your verified your link with Google, see point 2 at https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: Yes, I have verified my link with google which mentioned in point 2.
Shows that the URL is available to Google but it is still not working with my prefix /preview to open an app.
Is it still something which I have missed?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this (and remember the solution?). I have exactly the same issue.